# Prisma and MongoDB: Many-to-many nested create only populates one side of the relation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, prisma

I have a schema set up where Users can create many Photos, and then attach those photos to a single Post. Other users can repost others' photos, so I need a many to many relation between Photo and Post:

```
model User {
  id              String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  photos          Photo[]
  posts           Post[]
  ...
}

model Photo {
    id          String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    user        User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId      String   @db.ObjectId
    posts       Post[]   @relation(fields: [postIds], references: [id])
    postIds     String[] @db.ObjectId
    ...
}

model Post {
    id           String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    poster       User      @relation(fields: [posterId], references: [id])
    posterId     String    @db.ObjectId
    photos       Photo[]   @relation(fields: [photoIds], references: [id])
    photoIds     String[]  @db.ObjectId
    ...
}
```

I am able to create photos and posts just fine, but the problem is when I try to create a new post that connects the existing photos. This is my query:

```
return await prisma.user.update({
    where: {id},
    data: {
        posts: {
            create: {
                photoIds,
            },
        }
    }
})
```

This works for the Posts side of the relation, the Post's photoIds are populated correctly, however the Photo's postIds are left empty. I am not sure how to connect the other side of the relation.

The bizarre thing is that when I do a Post count query on the Photo, it returns the correct count number:

```
await prisma.user.findUnique({where: { id }}).photos({
    where: { id: photoId },
    select: {
        ...
        _count: {
            select: {
                posts: true,
            }
        },
    }
})
```

This query returns the correct post count for each photo, even though it's postIds list is empty. There must be something simple I am missing here, I have read the Prisma docs on many-to-many relations for MongoDB over and over again but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The secret sauce here is the "include" fields when you create or update.
Instead of updating the `user` type, just create the photos with the correct userId and the "include" field and it'll automatically link them, such that when you query for users, it'll have attached photos:

Instead of:

```
return await prisma.user.update({
    where: {id},
    data: {
        posts: {
            create: {
                photoIds,
            },
        }
    }
});
```

Use:

```
return await prisma.photo.create({
    data: {
       ...your photo data
       userId: '123'
    },
    include: {
      user: true
    }
})
```